# Передать параметр в gulp или как запускать таск под конкретные файлы

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Вопрос общий, но конкретно меня интересует компиляция конкретных файлов js под gulp.
Смотрите, есть такая структура папки `js`:

```
_js
  gallery_logic.js
  hello_logic.js
```

На выходе хочу получить минимизированную версию каждого файла, типа такого:

```
js
  gallery_logic.min.js
  hello_logic.min.js
```

Почему такую структуру, а не просто сконкатинировать в один файл и сжать? Раньше я так и делал, но решил избавиться от этого, поскольку под каждую структуру буду пихать соответствующий файл js.
Мне показалось это удобным, кому как, но задача именно такая.

Но это ещё не вся задача.
Есть таск gulp, который называется `watch`, он следить за файлами и при изменении в них, запускает соответствующий таск. Вот он:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/_js/*.js', ['js']);
});
```

А вот и сам таск `js`:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src(['assets/_js/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat())
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
});
```

Что эти два таска делают:

- `watch` смотрит за изменениями файлов (всех, так как в поисковой
  строке указана *), как я уже сказал.
- А таск `js` конкатинирует все файлы в папке (тоже - виной этому
  звездочка в запросе), сжимает пакетом `babel()` и выдает в папку
  `assets/js`.

Вроде всё прекрасно, но это не выполняет моим требованием, так как я хочу, чтобы каждый файл компилировался отдельно и выдавался отдельно.

И вот, собственно, подошли к вопросу и проблеме. Как я понял, можно выйти из этого положения, если найти способ передать путь измененного файла из таска `watch` в таск `js`, чтобы сформировать путь до файла, который нужно сжать и переименовать, и положить в папочку `js`.
И я не понимаю, как передать этот путь из таска `watch`.
Буду благодарен, если подскажете.

Comment: Правильным решением было бы написание таска `minify`, почему вы не хотите так сделать? Кто вас заставляет изменять таск `js`?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, не понял, какое написание таска `minify`? Почему он так называется? Функцию сжатия выполняет `babel()`. И чем этот новый таск будет отличаться от таска `js`?  Если ты думаешь, что это решит мою проблему, предложи код в ответе просто.

Comment: Можете как угодно назвать. Этот таск будет делать из filename.js файл filename.min.js и всё. Про babel в первой части вопроса вообще ничего не сказано.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, про сжатие во второй части вопроса говорится. Мне кажется, вопрос вообще не про сжатие.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, я не понял совет. Мне кажется, он не рабочий. Но если ты уверен, то приложи код.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, как ты будешь определять какое имя файла будет обрабатываться этим новым таском - меня интересует. Файла-то в примере два. Два таска будешь создавать?

Comment: Если вопрос не про сжатие, то про что же еще? Просто формулировка вопроса уже содержит неправильный путь развития задачи.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, я считаю, что идеально сформировал свой вопрос.

Comment: Я понял тебя, сейчас опишу.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55582/discussion-between-vostoksisters-and-zhukov-roman).

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, я чё-то погнался за одним, и забыл, почему я изначально решил "передавать" сурс измененного файла в таск `js`. Причина вот в этом: http://joxi.ru/brRnLyafJ8kjBr. То есть если файл изменен (один, я его просто сохраняю), то таск берет ВСЕ файлы и заного ВСЕ прогоняет через алгоритм в таске. И более того - 3 раза запускает рефреш браузера.  Поэтому нужно бы передать...

Answer (score 0):

Это не ответ на вопрос! Но решение моей конкретной задачи.
Просто задача решается другим, более легким способом, чем я предполагал в вопросе.

Разобрался с подсказкой от **Zhukov Roman**.

Нужно убрать из таска `concat()`, тогда таск не будет конкатить все файлы, а просто сделает с каждым файлом все остальные в цепочке задачи.
Также ещё указать в таске `js` строчку на добавление префикса:

```
.pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
```

Получается нужная мне структура на выдаче:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]